# How to disable livepatch tokens remotely

Tags: license, canonical-livepatch

I've enabled Cononical Livepatch services with my token on a virtual machine. The token allows me to enable livepatch on up to three machines.

To disable the token on a working machine we can use the command:

```
sudo snap run canonical-livepatch disable
```

My question is how do I disable the livepatch service on machines which I no longer have access to?

The reason I'm looking for an option to disable this granted licenses is because I'd like to use the license on three new machines.

I couldn't find such an option in the Canonical Livepatch Service Portal at https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/

If there is no such option, then perhaps the license is not in use or will be regranted if the machine is inactive (for a certain period of time). Can someone confirm this theory?

Comment: answered my question how to disable livepatch service w/o GUI. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The token is stored in `/var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/machine-token`.

The only option I found so far is to have a backup of the machine that you can boot in a virtual machine (if it wasn't a VM to begin with as in your case). Preferably you have a disk image that you can convert to a virtual machine image, but a tarball of the root partition may also work. I tried changing the hostname and chrooting with `/sys` `/proc` `/run` and `/dev` mounted but had no success, snap reported that it could not find the livepatch snap. The operation is successful when you see the following message:

```
Successfully disabled device. Removed machine-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Bear in mind that **machine token is not your authentication token**. Also I'm a bit in doubt about the limit and how it's supposed to work if there is no portal to enable and disable it (for non-Ubuntu advantage users).

> Q: But I don’t want to buy UA support!
>
> A: You don’t have to! Canonical is providing the Canonical Livepatch Service to community users of Ubuntu, at no charge for up to 3 machines (desktop, server, virtual machines, or cloud instances).
>   <sub>http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/10/canonical-livepatch.html</sub>

This is interesting, I just tried it out and enabled it on 4 machines. I went further and enabled 6 machines.

> Ubuntu Community users of the Canonical Livepatch Service who want to eliminate the small chance of being randomly chosen as a canary should enroll in the Ubuntu Advantage program (starting at $12/month).

The more free testers the better?